# correct way to represent the inductive reactance ? XL = ωL or XL = jωL

Tags: ac, inductive, reactance

In some cases the inductive reactance is mentioned with j and in some case it mentioned without j. so which is the correct way to mention the inductive reactance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reactance is imaginary impedance. The reactance is ωL, but the impedance is jωL.

> Both reactance \$X\$ and resistance \$R\$ are components of impedance \$Z\$.
>
> \$Z = R + jX\$

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance#Analysis)

Comment: I would point out that inductive reactance is positive, whereas capacitive reactance is negative.  Sorry to be pedantic, but it's an important point, especially when impedance matching.